# equals cannot convert from String to boolean

Tags: java, string, talend

I want to compare input String from Database in tMap component in Talend Open Studio. If my String is equal to "{}", I want to put there "nodata" string. Otherwise I leave the original input as it is.

My code in expression/filter in tMap:

```
(row1.parameter).equals("{}")?"nodata":row1.parameter
```

Error I'm getting:

**Detail Message: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to boolean**

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What type is `row1.parameter`? What type is the variable you're assigning this expression to?

Comment: I suppose you tried enclosing the entire expression before the question mark in parentheses?

Comment: Change your expression to `((row1.parameter).equals("{}"))?"nodata":row1.parameter`. And also, make sure that the other variable that you're assing value to is also a string.

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with what you have entered here (provided `row1.parameter` is a String). What you need to provide is how this is used, are you assigning it to a variable declaration? if so what type is the variable? or are you passing it into a method, if what is the Type of the parameter?

Comment: I've typed the expression in filter/expression field. My input (row1.parameter is a String; my output test.parameter is a String). I'm haven't assigned it to a variable (Var field in tMap). Thank you for suggestions. You where right about assigning the result to a String var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to assign the result to a `String` variable, like

```
String someVariable = row1.parameter.equals("{}") ? "nodata" : row1.parameter;
```

because your expression returns a String… Are you assigning it to a Boolean? If yes, that will cause / be a type mismatch.

Comment: I've typed the expression in filter/expression field. My input (row1.parameter is a String; my output test.parameter is a String). I'm haven't assigned it to a variable (Var field in tMap).
Your answer works. I've assigned the result to var in tMap. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're keeping the "Parameter" field, it sounds like your Output field that you are assigning 'Parameter' to is not a 'String' field, and is set as 'Boolean':

[image]

So the first point of call would be to check/change the output to a type of 'String':

[image]

Comment: My input and output is a String but I've put the expression in expression filter in output column. Then I've put the expression in var field in tMap everything works fine. Thank you for the answer :)